# How to achieve a sticky table header and few columns (with checkbox or inputs on each columns)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having problem using jquery library on getting this done. One problem that occur is that I cant check some checkbox on sticky columns, cant click and type on text fields, etc.

Im using this [jQuery Stick Table Headers](https://github.com/jpchip/stickytable) and checked the [demo](https://github.com/jpchip/stickytable#jquery-stick-table-headers). Made some changes, added a checkbox on the 1st row 1st column. But the checkbox is unclickable.

`sampel code >` [this](http://jsfiddle.net/btvf09h6/1/).

Comment: what are your changes? can you create it on https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I think you need to check [this.](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/)

Comment: @Chandrakant http://jsfiddle.net/btvf09h6/1/.

Comment: its rendering several tables and thats the main cause of that. those tables are with same data and overlapping each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help you!

Write this in css file

```
table.sticky-col{
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: seems like it worked (i can check stuffs now) but the the column wont stick on horizontal scroll.

Comment: just edited my answer, just remove previous style and try this new